# Continuity errors in "Callahan's Con" (by Spider Robinson)

Tags: continuity, callahans-crosstime-saloon

I was thinking about Robinson's *Callahan's Con* the other day, and remembering some continuity errors in the book that vexed me (I don't have an electronic version to search through, so forgive my lack of lengthy quotes):

Example 1:

Field Agent Czrjghnczl gives Jake her cellphone on page 201, Jake breaks it by falling on it on page 225 but by page 230

> nobody would answer Doc's phone, because I'd broken it...

Example 2:

On page 36, Czrjghnczl slams a gate so hard that the gate cracks, but when Jake looks at the gate again on page 91,  he notes that the crack was made by "Little Nuts" (Tony Donuts, Jr.).

Example 3:

On page 63, Jake, Zoey and Erin are talking when Tony Donuts walks in, and tries to shake Jake down. During that brief conversation (on page 69), Jake suddenly doesn't know where Zoey is or when she'll be back (he thinks to himself that he doesn't know if she's rehearsing or setting up for a gig - he's not lying to Tony).

(possibly there are other errors that I've forgotten and couldn't find in a quick skim)

1. Is there some in-universe explanation I'm missing for these errors?
2. Has Spider mentioned a reason for these errors (most of them relate in some way to Czrjghnczl - perhaps she was introduced late in the writing process and the changes weren't properly smoothed through)?